# Microsoft Azure App Service Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-app-service-plans

I have a doubt for purchase a microsoft azure app service to host my app. I have already tested the free profile and i am concerned to switch to a basic profile.
That's my question.
I have seen on this table on azure website [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) which i'll have 10GB of disk space for my application files.
When i went on price calculator i see this [image]
Well my question is:
Why here i see 10GB of **temporary** storage? will i lose my application files located in the wwwroot folder anytime?

Comment: This answer is likely highly out of date in 2023

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> will i lose my application files located in the wwwroot folder anytime?

It will not be lost if you application files located in the wwwroot folder.We could get the answer from the [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system).

> **Persisted files**
>
> This is what you can view as your web site's files. They follow a structure described here. They are rooted in **d:\home**, which can also be found using the %HOME% environment variable.
>
> These files are persistent, meaning that you can rely on them staying there until you do something to change them. Also, they are shared between all instances of your site (when you scale it up to multiple instances). Internally, the way this works is that they are stored in Azure Storage instead of living on the local file system.
>
> Free and Shared sites get 1GB of space, Basic sites get 10GB, and Standard sites get 50GB
>
> **Temporary files**
>
> A number of common Windows locations are using temporary storage on the local machine. For instance
>
> %APPDATA% points to something like D:\local\AppData.
>   %TMP% goes to D:\local\Temp.
>   Unlike Persisted files, these files are not shared among site instances. Also, you cannot rely on them staying there. For instance, if you restart a web app, you'll find that all of these folders get reset to their original state.
>
> For **Free, Shared and Consumptio**n (Functions) sites, there is a **500MB** limit for all these locations together (i.e. not per-folder). For **Standard and Basic** sites, the limit is very high (over **100GB**).

We could check the application files in the **D:\home\site\wwwroot** from the Azure kudu tool(https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net/).

[image: kudu console]

Available disk space is shown on the **Environment** page:

[image: environment page]

Comment: Or someone could fix the pricing calculator. I'll send some feedback.

Comment: Added one more screenshot to your answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  evilSnobu, that's what i need :)