# how to fix 'There is not enough space on the disk.'?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

ASP disk usage in App service environment shows 2.5 gb used disk of 1024 gb.
Web app is  Isolated I2 with Scale out=10 instance and 1 app.

Do I get 1 tb  combined for all asp in the ASE?

the wiki says : An App Service plan in the Isolated pricing SKU has a limit of 250 GB - this is confusing.

Why do I get "not enough space on the disk.' when the job is running and downloading files?
Thanks, Peter

Comment: Azure web app does not recommend storing files in the project folder, that is, under the wwwroot folder.

Comment: It is recommended that you learn and use azure storage. If you do not want to change the code, you can only increase the pricing tier.

Comment: My files are in local\temp. Can you explain why the  Disk used is so small, yet I get errors about 'out of disk'?

Comment: Pls check this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218362/microsoft-azure-app-service-storage

Comment: Our webapp has it's own disk size, check it first.

Comment: I read the link you supplied. it mentions that local/temp is temporary. but my question is how to expand local/temp .